# Change language to Firebase exceptions

Tags: android, firebase

I'm calling to a Firebase method and in case of Exception I want to return the exception message in Spanish but **task.getException().getMessage()** is returning it in English instead.

Snippet code:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    // do something
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Do I have to change something in Firebase configuration? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw the `Exception` returned by `task.getException` inside a try-catch-block. All the exeptions that are thrown are in `english`. Below, each type of Exception that may be thrown by the method you are using.

I have uses an example from the `OnCompleteListener` for the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method. Please see the follwing code:

```
if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
    try {
        throw task.getException();
    } catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
        //do somethig
    } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        //do somethig
    } catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
        //do somethig
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the actual use of the `getLocalizedMessage()` ?

Comment: @RamiAlloush I don't see any `getLocalizedMessage()` here.

Comment: my question was why can't we use `task.getException().getLocalizedMessage()`

Comment: @RamiAlloush Yes, you can use it to return the name of the exception in the local language of the user.

Answer (score 0):

`getLocalizedMessage()` does give you the description of the exception (the name is given by `task.getException().getClass().getSimpleName()`) but still in English (therefore with no difference from `getMessage()`).
In order to make use of its "localized" features, you first need to override the method according to your needs.
You can see a complete example of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988491/difference-between-e-getmessage-and-e-getlocalizedmessage), although for the simple purpose mentioned here, I would definitely stick with Alex's solution.