# Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, javafx

I am trying to create a simple WorkbenchFX based project (Java 11) using Maven in the Eclipse IDE but I cannot get it to work because of the following error

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project test_workbenchfx: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]**

The entire console output is;

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.workfx:test_workbenchfx >---------------------
[INFO] Building test_workbenchfx 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test_workbenchfx ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\JD\eclipse-workspace\test_workbenchfx\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ test_workbenchfx >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test_workbenchfx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ test_workbenchfx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\JD\eclipse-workspace\test_workbenchfx\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ test_workbenchfx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) @ test_workbenchfx ---
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:4323)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:4310)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.addAll(ObservableListBase.java:246)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.binding.ListExpression.addAll(ListExpression.java:360)
    at com.dlsc.workbenchfx.Workbench.initModules(Workbench.java:386)
    at com.dlsc.workbenchfx.Workbench.<init>(Workbench.java:339)
    at com.dlsc.workbenchfx.Workbench$WorkbenchBuilder.build(Workbench.java:311)
    at com.workfx.test_workbenchfx.App.initWorkbench(App.java:76)
    at com.workfx.test_workbenchfx.App.start(App.java:59)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.workfx.test_workbenchfx.App
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.357 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-10T19:44:03+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) on project test_workbenchfx: Error: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I built the Maven project using the goal: **clean javafx:run**

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.workfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_workbenchfx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.dlsc.workbenchfx</groupId>
          <artifactId>workbenchfx-core</artifactId>
          <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.workfx.test_workbenchfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>
            -->

            <!-- 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.workfx.test_workbenchfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>        
            -->

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The project's main class is

```
package com.workfx.test_workbenchfx;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import com.dlsc.workbenchfx.Workbench;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * JavaFX Workbench App
 */
public class App extends Application {

  private Workbench wbench;

  /**
   * Application entry point
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988491/difference-between-e-getmessage-and-e-getlocalizedmessage
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);

    launch(args);

  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // preferences = new Preferences();

    // Initialize the workbench
    Scene myScene = new Scene(initWorkbench());

    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(1300);
    primaryStage.setHeight(730);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

    // initNightMode();
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private Workbench initWorkbench() {

    wbench = Workbench.builder(null).build();

    return wbench;
  }

}
```

I would really appreciate some help to get around this problem because nothing I've tried thus far (clean, update, rebuild) works.

Thanks a lot for your kind assistance.

JD

Comment: Can you post the actual code that's responsible for the exception, indicate which variable is null, and why you think it shouldn't be null?

Answer (score 0):

**James_D** Thanks a lot. It was so obvious after I read your comment. I passed null as a parameter into Workbench.builder() in the initWorkbench() method. Once I removed it and added a proper class, it worked.